# Are Shudras allowed to do Adhyayan of (read or recite) Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, shudra

Are Shudras allowed to do adhyayan of Mahabharata ?
Does Mahabharata say that Shudras are qualified to read Mahabharata ?
Note : plz give reference form Mahabharata only.

Comment: Please stop derriding hinduism by asking caste  based questions

Comment: Mahabharata Adi Parva explains that Vyasa wrote this for everyone.

Comment: Can you give reference

Comment: Where did you read they can't?

Comment: I seen in Mahabharata trivarnas are study this Mahabharata. But shudra and womens are not study they are hear form brahmana

Comment: I very first chapter is telling

Answer (score 2):

In Bhavishya Parva of Harivamsha (from critical edition by Bibek Debroy) -

> “A man who reads this great poem composed by the great-souled rishi is worshipped. He obtains an excellent lifespan, which is extremely difficult to obtain. He attains emancipation and the fruits of knowing everything. Just as Shatakratu was released from his sins, a man who reads this is freed from his sins. In that way, he also obtains all the diverse objects of desire. Once all desire has been satisfied, he enjoys bliss for a long period of time. A tree yields auspicious fruit and from that fruit, trees are again generated. In that way, these words were composed by the rishi and also enhance the maharshi’s power. Those who are without sons obtain extremely radiant sons. Those who have dislodged regain their own status again. There is no disease and there is freedom from bondage. One obtains the fruits of auspicious rites and all the qualities. If a maiden listens to the auspicious words of the sage, she obtains a virtuous husband. She gives birth to handsome sons who possess all the qualities, are full of valour and delight people. Those who follow the conduct of kshatriyas conquer the earth. They obtain unmatched riches and victory over “enemies. Vaishyas obtain large quantities of wealth. **Shudras who listen to this obtain a desirable end.** This is the ancient account of the conduct of great-souled ones. A person who studies it obtains auspicious intelligence. He abandons misery and becomes free from attachment. Detached, he roams around the earth. You must remember that this account was recited in an assembly of brahmanas. If you remember this, patience will again be generated in you and will roam around the world, happy. The great-souled rishi composed this account about the conduct of those who were brave in their deeds. I have recounted it, briefly and in detail. What else do you desire that I should speak about?”

End of Harivamsha

Also end of mahabharata that is chapter 5 of Svargarohanika Parva
(again critical edition) which is on benefits of reading mahabharata doesn't contain any verse which may imply any restriction on reading/hearing mahabharata. Rather 43rd verse of chapter 5 says -

> itihAsamimaM puNyaM mahArthaM vedasaMmitam |
> shrAvayedyastu varNA.nstrInkRRitvA brAhmaNamagrataH

which translates to - This history is sacred, is deep in meaning, and regarded as equal to the Vedas. That man, O Saunaka, who hears this history, placing a Brahmana before him, acquires both fame and the fruition of all his wishes

Comment: I told I want reference form Mahabharata . not Form bhagavatam . I too know bhagavatam as sloka

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Now I hope you got your answer

Comment: Sir it is telling hearing . I am asking about reading

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud please don't call me sir because for sure I am younger and have less knowledge than you. Regarding your question I will modify my answer again in few time

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely. Shudras are a part of society and they were respected very much. It is because of these Hinduphobic Media, Cinema and Books that Shudras are seen as "lower" people. Shudras and Women both could read Mahabharata.

Reference from Mahabharata
Bhagavad Gita

Verse ( 5. 18)

vidyä-vinaya-sampanne
brähmaëe gavi hastini
çuni caiva çva-päke ca
paëòitäù sama-darçinaù

**The humble sages, by virtue of true knowledge, see with equal vision a
learned and gentle brähmana, a cow, an elephant, a dog and a dog-eater
[outcaste].**

I hope this answers your question.

Hare Krishna! Ram Ram

Comment: By giving this reference you will tell shudra can Also read Vedas

Comment: I too know this reference . asked reference for reading Mahabharata.  Not seeing equal view on all